# Add custom error bars to seaborn regplot and residplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

Is there a way to add custom error bars to seaborn regplot and residplot like one can do with matplotlib errorbar using yerr? Examples are here; if I just add a yerr argument an error occurs,

```
import seaborn as sns

xd = [1,2,3,4,6,7]
yd = [2,4,7,9,12,14]
yerrd = [1,2,1,3,1,4]

sns.regplot(xd, yd)

sns.residplot(xd, yd)
```

Answer (score 2):

Draw the errorbars using matplotlib's `errorbar`

```
xd = [1,2,3,4,6,7]
yd = [2,4,7,9,12,14]
yerrd = [1,2,1,3,1,4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.regplot(xd, yd, ax=ax)
ax.errorbar(xd, yd, yerr=yerrd, fmt='none', capsize=5, zorder=1, color='C0')
```

[image]

Comment: This is not so quick with residplot. The idea is to use seaborn functionality, but just add error bars to it.

Comment: this is not possible with the seaborn functions