# Can you add standard deviations to the points in seaborn regplot?

Tags: python, plot, regression, seaborn

I have annual data of when the first day with temperatures exceeding 15 degrees occurs in the Arctic. I plot it in a `sns.regplot` with the points included, however, these are without standard deviation. Can I include this in the plot for the points?

```
x = np.arange([2001,2019])
y = [134.759135, 139.105059, 131.554803, 121.199588, 121.316233, 126.676592, 132.474224, 116.740998, 130.837217, 129.063968, 121.302684, 130.090100, 131.298788, 140.051307 , 117.834925, 119.612732, 117.086247, 120.503183]
std = [14.143995, 14.289196, 12.285933, 15.264013, 12.132436, 9.656137, 11.454564, 12.905132, 12.175471, 10.644168, 12.096718, 11.288746, 12.786497, 11.302180, 10.407992, 13.354334, 11.042383, 10.355433

sns.regplot(x = x, y = y)
ax.set_ylim(100,175)
```

[image]

I would like to also provide the reader with standard deviation (`std`) for each of the points in the plot. Is that possible in the `sns.regplot`?

Comment: See [Add custom error bars to seaborn regplot and residplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64787817/add-custom-error-bars-to-seaborn-regplot-and-residplot)

Comment: Yes please - thanks!